# TeXworks stopped creating pdf's

Tags: compiling, texworks

I just installed TeXworks on my MacBook pro and I created a simple `.tex` file. It worked just fine and created the PDF any time I ran 'pdfLaTeX'.

Now that I've created a new file it doesn't create the PDF any more.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{ \textbf{Interação e Concorrência} }
\author{Limiano}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What does the `.log` file say?

Comment: @ChrisS Thank you for the warm welcome. This is my working example :

\documentclass{article}

\title{   \textbf{Interação e Concorrência} }

\author{Limiano}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Comment: @JosephWright in the end it says :

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: @LuísCarvalho When you add a MWE, you can add it to your original question (instead of a comment) by clicking 'edit' at the bottom of the question. Your MWE produces no output because you haven't added anything to the page: all that `\title` and `\author` do is store that information away; you have to add `\maketitle` to your document (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) for anything to show up.

Answer (score 4):

Your document produces no PDF output because the actual document has no content. Although you've defined a title and author, this information is not added to the document until you use `\maketitle`.